# Problem upgrading SDL Tridion 2013 Web Application to SDL WEB 8.5 (Spring, Hibernate)

Tags: web8.5, upgrade, spring

We're upgrading from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 to SDL WEB 8.5 and we've found this issue:

Our client's web application (the one that is published by Tridion) uses Hibernate and Spring Frameworks. When we upgrade the web application to SDL WEB 8.5 we need to change these frameworks to a new version, with the new versions our client's code is failing.

They have their application working with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR 1, Spring 3 and Hibernate 4. With SDL WEB 8.5 we need to upgrade the Spring Framework to version 4 and the Hibernate framework to version 5. They have to change a lot of code to make it work in Hibernate 5.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.
David.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Web 8.5 the Content Delivery framework is via microservices. So it really doesn’t matter what versions of Spring or Hibernate the app is using, unless you’re trying to use the legacy “in-process” configuration approach. If you upgrade to using microservices, then the Spring and Hibernate dependency is on the service itself, which is separate from your web app (the services are their own independent app). If, however, you’re trying to make it all work “in-process” via JDBC just like with pre-Web 8 versions of Tridion, then you’re gonna have to play around with different spring and Hibernate jars/versions until you find a common one that works (a good reason to just upgrade to microservices)